# using Linq to iterate over an array and create a new List of objects?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List<> of type GameResult that I want to populate with a new instance of the class GameResult using data from an array(gamerArray).

So I have this using a foreach loop.

```
 List<GameResult> gameResults = new List<GameResult>();
 foreach (var g in gamerArray.GamePlayers)
        {
            gameResults.Add(
                new GameResult
                {
                    GameID = g.GameID,
                    GameName = g.GameName,
                    SessionStart = g.StartTime,
                    SessionEnd = g.EndTime,
                    SessionMessage = "You Won!"
                });
        }
```

Is there a way to use Linq to iterate over the array and create the new List of GameResult objects?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
List<GameResult> gameResults = gamerArray.GamePlayers.Select(g => new GameResult
{
    GameID = g.GameID,
    GameName = g.GameName,
    SessionStart = g.StartTime,
    SessionEnd = g.EndTime,
    SessionMessage = "You Won!"
}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
gameResults = gamerArray.GamePlayers.Select(g => new GameResult
                {
                    GameID = g.GameID,
                    GameName = g.GameName,
                    SessionStart = g.StartTime,
                    SessionEnd = g.EndTime,
                    SessionMessage = "You Won!"
                }).ToList();
```

[Linq Select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netcore-3.0)